# How many such different permutations?

Tags: combinatorics

How many different permutations are from 1 to n in which for any x the following number is not equal to x + 1 ?

I suppose $$n! + \sum_{k=1}^n (-1)^k(n-k)(n-k)! $$

But is it true?

Comment: Explain your first sentence again....."following number"?

Comment: OEIS: [A000255](http://oeis.org/A000255)